# PHP: range and foreach

Tags: php, arrays, random, multidimensional-array, range

I'm working with percents and rand(), I'm trying to create an array from 0 to 25 then 25 to 50 then 50 to 80.
But I got this array:

```
[0] => 55
[1] => 56
[2] => 57
[3] => 58
[4] => 59
[5] => 60
[6] => 61
[7] => 62
[8] => 63
[9] => 64
[10] => 65
[11] => 66
[12] => 67
[13] => 68
[14] => 69
[15] => 70
[16] => 71
[17] => 72
[18] => 73
[19] => 74
[20] => 75
[21] => 76
[22] => 77
[23] => 78
[24] => 79
[25] => 80
```

I want to create an array from 0 to 80.
My code is:

```
foreach($list_percents as $redir) {
    $percent_array=range($inicial,($inicial+$redir->percent));
    $percent_array=array_fill($inicial, $redir->percent, $redir->url);
    $inicial=($inicial+$redir->percent);
}
print_r($percent_array);
```

Comment: What is `$redir` and why do you overwrite `$percent_array`with `array_fill` after filling it with `range`?

Comment: `$percent_array = range(0,80);`?

Comment: You are overriding `$percent-array` immediately on lines 2 and 3